# Get averages of lists in a dictionary

Tags: python

I have a dictionary that has lists inside it eg:

```
dict = {'Monday,': [10, 20], 'Tuesday,': [20, 20], 'Wednesday,': [30, 40], 'Thursday,': [5, 25], 'Friday,': [100, 20], 'Saturday,': [40, 10], 'Sunday,': [35, 25]}
```

And I need to get an average of each day eg:

```
{'Monday,': [15.00], 'Tuesday,': [20.00], 'Wednesday,': [35.00], 'Thursday,': [15.00], 'Friday,': [60.00], 'Saturday,': [25.00], 'Sunday,': [30.00]}
```

I have this at the moment but it is not working

```
average = sum(dict) / len(dict)
```

Comment: `{k: sum(xs) / len(xs) for k, xs in d.items()}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

first, please don't name your `dict` as `dict` because that's a name of a python built-in

This will work for you:

```
average = {key: sum(val)/len(val) for key, val in dict.items()}
```

but beware that you assumed all lists are of numbers and no list is empty.

Comment: Sorry dict was just an example name

Comment: I am get an error - AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'items' How can I fix this?

Comment: @JTiger that means your variable (which named `dict` in your example) is not a dict type